# Proofs of matrix multiplication distributivity over addition (right and left), and associativity. are these correct?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

So I don't have a lot of familiarity with the properties of summation, so I'm asking whether I'm using them righ.
So let $A,B,C \in M_{m,n}(\mathbb{K})$, what I have to show is that:

1. $A(B+C)=AB+AC$
2. $(B+C)A=BA+CA$
3. $A(BC)=(AB)C$

1. Let $a_{ij}$ be the entry in the i-th row and j-th column, we define $AB$ in the following way:$$(AB)_{ij}:=\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{ik}b_{kj}$$
   So, let's compute $(A(B+C))_{ij}$, $$(A(B+C))_{ij}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{ik}(b+c)_{kj}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{ik}(b_{kj}+c_{kj})=\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{ij}b_{kj}+a_{ik}c_{kj}=$$ $$= \sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{ik}b_{kj}+\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{ik}c_{kj}=(AB)_{ij}+(AC)_{ij}=$$
   $$= (AB+AC)_{ij}$$
2. The proof is basically identical
3. Now I'm stuck with associativity, $$(A(BC))_{ij}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{ik}(\sum_{\gamma=1}^{n}b_{k\gamma}c_{\gamma j})=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\Big(\sum_{\gamma=1}^{n}a_{ik}b_{k\gamma}c_{\gamma j}\Big)$$
   and that's where I'm at, I guess I have to do a change of indicies at some point, I don't know whether I'm allow to put parenthesis before $c_{\gamma j}$. Please help

Comment: What you've done so far is good! To finish associativity, try rearranging the summation: swap $\sum_{k=1}^n$ with $\sum_{\gamma=1}^n$. Doing this simply sums the terms in a different order, which produces the same number by commutativity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can switch the summations so $$\sum_{k=1}^n\sum_{\gamma=1}^n =\sum_{\gamma=1}^n\sum_{k=1}^n$$

Now you can pull $c_{yj}$ to get $$\sum_{\gamma=1}^n c_{\gamma j} \sum_{k=1}^na_{ik}b_{k\gamma}=\\=\sum_{\gamma=1}^n c_{\gamma j}(AB)_{i\gamma}= \\=\sum_{\gamma=1}^n (AB)_{i\gamma}c_{\gamma j}=\\=((AB)C)_{ij} $$